# Vidusl Studio Code not starting jupyter kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interpreter

My Visual Studio Code (VSC) did stop working for some Reason. It worked fine about a week ago. I'm using Arch Linux and updated all packages. The code is in a .ipynb file `import sys`.

If I want to run code with `Shift + Enter` then the select Kernel pops up, but it is empty and stays empty forever. If I click the button on the right to select a kernel, the same thing pops up and stays empty. The arrows to run the code give the same result.

I cab run code from the Linux terminal and also start a jupyter notebook from the terminal and run the code just fine. I can also use the terminal within VSC.

`Shift + Ctrl + P` `Python: Select Interpreter` shows my python paths and also my virtual environments with the correct tags. Also created a new virtual environment in the same folder as the code under ENV/ and added the path here by hand. The Code is still not executing.

`Shift + Ctrl + P` `Jupyter: Select Interpreter to start jupyter server` shows the same environments, but regardless of the selection, the code is not working.

Also tried to create a new notebook, restarting VSC and rebooting the computer. Python works fine in the console and also running code from .py files works fine. `Shift + Enter` in a .py file opens the terminal on the bottom of VSC and executes just fine.

Any help is appreciated! Otherwise I'll just reinstall everything.